# Wpf and C # capture webcam and network cameras

Tags: c#, wpf, camera, media

I am looking for a solution for capturing webcam and network cameras.
I've done some research on the internet but so far I haven't been able to find a solution that was viable for my problem. I need my application to list all available cameras and give me the option to select one to display. I also need an option that allows me to take a print of the camera and save it in a folder.
My research took me to some proprietary solutions and to some tutorials that didn't solve my problem, like these.

Wpf-MediaKit: https://github.com/Sascha-L/WPF-MediaKit

Media Capture: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/basic-photo-video-and-audio-capture-with-mediacapture

LeadTools: https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/multimedia/capture?

Does anyone know any OpenSource library that solves my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect camera devices on your system, use `ManagementObjectSearcher` and figure out the string query to use for the camera(s) you want to find.  Google "ManagementObjectSearcher camera devices" on how to do it, I don't have a direct solution.

To read the camera stream in C# (so that you can capture a frame), look into [OpenCVSharp](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp) and the online samples it provides in github.

Good luck!

Comment: I am really satisfied with the results offered by OpenCvSharp. With your indication, my research became easier and I got a good sequence of videos on Youtube that accelerated the process of my implementation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPxSGFYIzuo&list=PLnFhdlXrgEx6DMADqFBTzoXBhARb4MTO9.

Comment: As for ManagementObjectSearcher I haven't done any tests yet because I only have my notebook's built-in camera to do the tests. But as soon as possible, I leave my comments here. Thank you.