# How to take high quality photo from integrated camera in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, camera, photo

I'm implementing WPF app where I need to take high quality photos from integrated camera. So far I've been successful with capturing video and taking frames from it (described for example here: [Wpf and C # capture webcam and network cameras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62604177/wpf-and-c-capture-webcam-and-network-cameras)).

But this is not what I want - because video frame quality is not so great. I have MS Surface 4 Pro which has 8Mpx camera with full HD video support and with the above method I'm able to just get full HD frame from it. But I would like to have full 8Mpx picture, like it is possible to take in the native Windows Camera app.

In UWP I would probably have been successful with CameraCaptureUI class, but I didn't find any clues for WPF.

Does anyone has an idea how this could be implemented?

Comment: Show the actual capture code you are using, for reference

Comment: I tested several capture libraries like WPF MediaKit, WpfCap, OpenCVSharp. Using their sample apps. But they all work on the same principle - take frame from video stream which doesn't provide the highest resolution available on my device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found out that XAML Islands do work with .NET Framework 4.8. So I've been able to implement a WPF solution using UWP components MediaCapture and CaptureElement. With that I can take photos with full resolution which was my goal.

Simple sample project can be found here: https://github.com/ondrasvoboda/WPFCamera, consider it just as a proof of concept.

Answer (score 0):

If your app will run on Windows 10 or above, you can now use most of the APIs from Windows 10 in a WPF application.

https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/04/30/calling-windows-10-apis-from-a-desktop-application-just-got-easier/

Comment: Looks interesting. Can you provide some example how control camera using this API? Mainly I would need to display preview and take a photo.

Comment: I can see if i can dig something out, but once you've added the nuget package you should be able to import the same namespaces and use the same code and a normal UWP app.  I think you can host a UWP control in WPF too - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/host-custom-control-with-xaml-islands

Comment: That control hosting won't work for me - "XAML Islands are not yet supported in apps that target .NET 5, or in apps that any version of the .NET Framework" - I'm targeting .NET Framework 4.8